# Loop an existing script over multiple PDF files in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script which runs on single input PDF file. Is there a way that this script can run for multiple PDF files in a directory.

The below snippet where single PDF input file is

```
# Select the Master PDF Path. Located in "INPUT" folder
masterPDF_path = r"C:\Users\rohitpandey\Downloads\OneDrive_1_1-25-2023\CLAIMS Analysis\Format 2(Wire)"
master_pdf_document = 'Payment# 79724.pdf'
```

The complete script that runs on a single PDF file is as below :-

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import fitz
from datetime import datetime
import os

# Select the Master PDF Path. Located in "INPUT" folder
masterPDF_path = r"C:\Users\rohitpandey\Downloads\OneDrive_1_1-25-2023\CLAIMS Analysis\Format 2(Wire)"
master_pdf_document = 'Payment# 79724.pdf'

os.chdir(masterPDF_path)

# Choose the Path of Where the Doc Split Invoices should go. Located in "OUTPUT" folder
docSplit_dumpPath = r"C:\Users\rohitpandey\Downloads\OneDrive_1_1-25-2023\New folder"

#=========================================================================================#
#===================================== GET NUMBER OF PAGES ===============================#
#=========================================================================================#

String1 = "WIRE TRANSFER/ACH RECORD VOUCHER"

page_range = {}
pdfstarter = 0

doc = fitz.open(masterPDF_path+ "\\" + master_pdf_document)
docPageCount = doc.page_count

#================= PARSE PDF INTO THE DICTIONARY - LONG COMPUTE TIME ======================#
for i in range(0, docPageCount):
    pageText = doc.load_page(i)
    totalpage = i + 1
    pageiText = pageText.get_text('text')
    if String1 in pageiText:
        page_range.update({pdfstarter:totalpage})
        pdfstarter = totalpage
    #print("Current Page: ", i, " out of ", docPageCount)

    
#================= PARSE PDF INTO THE DICTIONARY - LONG COMPUTE TIME ======================#
invoiceList = []
for i in range(0,docPageCount):
    pageText = doc.load_page(i)
    pageiText = pageText.get_text('text')
    if String1 in pageiText:
        pageiText = pageiText.split("\n")
        test_list = pageiText
        # Checking if exists in list
        for i in test_list:
            if(i == String1):
                invoice = "PAYMENT_WIRE_BANK STATEMENT_STEP_1_" + master_pdf_document
                #print(invoice)
                invoiceList.append(invoice)
                
#========================================= SETUP ==========================================#
### SPLITING INTO n
n = int(len(invoiceList))
### CREATING FOUR LIST OF Invoice LIST
fourSplit_invoiceList = [invoiceList[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(invoiceList), n)]
### CONVERTING DIC TO LIST CONTAINING TUPLES
page_rangeList = [(k,v) for k, v in page_range.items()]
### CREATING FOUR LIST OF PAGE RANGE
fourSplit_pageRange = [page_rangeList[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(page_rangeList), n)]

TotalNumberOfDocs = len(fourSplit_invoiceList[0])


#=========================================================================================#

 

#=========================================================================================#
#==================================== CREATE PDFs ========================================#
#=========================================================================================#
openpdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(masterPDF_path + "\\" + master_pdf_document)

 

for i in range(len(fourSplit_invoiceList[0])):
    page_numberstart = fourSplit_pageRange[0][i][0]
    page_numberend = fourSplit_pageRange[0][i][1]        
    outputfile = fourSplit_invoiceList[0][i]
    outputfile = os.path.join(docSplit_dumpPath, outputfile)

    try:
        assert page_numberstart < openpdf.numPages
        pdf_writer1 = PdfFileWriter()
        for page in range(page_numberstart, page_numberend):
            pdf_writer1.addPage(openpdf.getPage(page))

 

        with open("{}".format(outputfile), 'wb') as file0:
            pdf_writer1.write(file0)

 

    except AssertionError as e:
        print("Error: The PDF you are cutting has less pages than you want to cut!")
```

Comment: Convert your script to a function and have a look to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of file names you can loop over them:

```py
files = ['Payment# 1.pdf', 'Payment# 2.pdf']
for file in files:
  master_pdf_document = file
```

Or, if you want to loop over your payment numbers and the 'Payment' string remains unchanged:

```py
payment_numbers = [1,2]
for payment_number in payment_numbers:
  master_pdf_document = 'Payment# '+str(payment_number)+'.pdf'
```